# OutputStream code not giving any errors but txt file is missing

Tags: java, outputstream, printwriter

I'm trying to get my program to save the output to a file for debugging purposes. The problem is, it compiles without any errors while not creating a file anywhere to be seen. This is probably something very simple but I can't figure it out, haven't coded in Java in a while.

```
public static void main(String[] Args) {
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream("out.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PrintWriter ps = new PrintWriter(out);
    for (int l = 1; l < 1001; l++) {
        ps.println((translation(makeString(l))));
        System.out.println((translation(makeString(l))));
    }
    try {
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you searching your file? Because it's inside the directory you are executing your program.

Comment: Where do you run this progam in command line or IDE like Eclipse

Comment: checked, double-checked... not there! Also, I'm not sure it's relevant but i'm using Eclipse. Maybe it saves its files elsewhere?

Comment: A serialised file is not a text file. Don't call it 'out.txt'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running this code in eclipse, search in the `workspace/project` folder, you should find one there

Answer (score 2):

You are creating FileOutputStream without absolute path. The result will be relative to program's current directory.  Following shows how to give an absolute path.

```
public static void main(String[] Args) {
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream("c:\\out.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PrintWriter ps = new PrintWriter(out);
    for (int l = 1; l < 1001; l++) {
        ps.println((translation(makeString(l))));
        System.out.println((translation(makeString(l))));
    }
    try {
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

will make your file appear on C: drive root folder...

Comment: Thanks, guys. My "problem" is solved. As for Andrea's suggestion, Eclipse says **"Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"**

Answer (score 1):

FileOutputStream creates the file if it does not exist: See [FileOutputStream(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String%29)

The file will be in the current directory when you run it. TO see where the code is being run, add the following line:

```
System.out.println(new java.io.File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

This will print out the current working directory.